# Scroll bar issue with iframe

Tags: html, css, iframe

The issue I am facing is that:
When I set an iframe - in my html website – in order to show another html page, i get 2 scroll bars on the left but I cant scroll at all. 
What I want is to scroll the main page and not the pages inside the iframes.

Iframes:

```
<div class="sixteen columns">
<div id="main"  style="position: absolute">
    <iframe src="html5/Project1.html" height="700px" width=" 1000" scrolling="no"></iframe>

</div>
```

The problem exists on IE and FF not on Chrome.

Comment: u can use html "overflow" attr for this.

Comment: By the way, it looks like you're using a class name with a space in it ("sixteen columns"), and that won't work how you expect.

Comment: @bobtato what if it is two classes? Kartikeya, there is no overflow **attribute**.

Comment: If it's two classes there's no problem! I just thought the OP might have meant `class="sixteen_columns"`.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 <iframe src="html5/Project1.html" style="overflow:hidden;width:1000px;height:70px"</iframe>
```

Comment: It doesn't work and it breaks down the ordinance of the iframe

Comment: What do you mean by ordinance?